# a function that points at itself

Tags: ocaml

I am lost in the following example on page 106 from the book titled Developing Applications with Objective Camel.

```
let nil_assoc = function x -> raise Not found ; ;
let l = ref nil_assoc;;
let add_assoc_again (k,v) l = l := (function x -> if x=k then v else !l x) ; ;
add_assoc_again ('1',1) l ; ;
add_assoc_again ('2',2) l ; ;
```

The resulting value for l is a function that points at itself and therefore loops.

I would have thought that the value for l after `add_assoc_again ('1', 1) l ;;` is
function

```
x -> if x = '1' then 1 else nil_assoc x;;
```

In continuation, the resulting value for l after `add_assoc_again ('2', 2) l ;;` should be 
function

```
x -> if x ='2' then 2 else ( function x -> if x = '1' then 1 else nil_assoc x ) x;;
```

I don't see why the resulting value for l is a function that points at itself and therefore the program hangs and loops

Comment: Now that's some creative formatting... (and I must assume it's intentional =/)

Answer (score 3):

`!l` does not get evaluated when you call `add_assoc_again`, it is evaluated when you call the function created by the call. At this point `l` will point to that function, so that's why you get the infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

There is a slightly modified version of this code in the new book http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/oreilly-book/ocaml-ora-book.pdf which seems to me more clear :

```
let nil_assoc = function x -> raise Not_found ;;
let add_assoc (k,v) l = function x -> if x = k then v else l x ;;
val add_assoc : 'a * 'b -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'b = <fun>
```

the argument `l` is clearly a function `('a -> 'b)` in the signature of `add_assoc`, and hence, is not evaluated till it gets called (upon the failure of the if test).

The code continues :

```
# let l1 = add_assoc (1, 1) nil_assoc;;
```

here, `l1` is equivalent to `fun x -> if x = 1 then 1 else nil_assoc x`

```
# let l2 = add_assoc (2, 2) l1;;
```

`l2` is `fun x -> if x = 2 then 2 else (fun y -> if y = 1 then 1 else nil_assoc y) 2`

which is very simple to understand compared to the version you privided.